# Как посчитать сложность алгоритма? О-символика

Tags: c#, task

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int operations = 0;
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i += 2)
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    operations++;
            Console.WriteLine(operations);
        }
        // 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Дополните вопрос вашей попыткой оценить сложность. Это учебное задание, без вашего решения правила запрещают помогать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy никто не запрещает, помогайте если желаете. Здесь не принято отвечать на вопросы, где автор сдампил домашку, ну потому что иначе мы утонем в таких вопросах. Но никто не запрещает, особенно если вы знаете, как сделать полезный ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Вот хорошая статья на эту тему:

> https://habr.com/ru/post/104219/

Вкратце - надо посчитать максимальное количество вложенных циклов, такая и будет степень у полинома в O (но есть нюансы).

В данном примере сложность - O((n^2)/2) = O(n^2), т.к. алгоритмическая сложность вычисляется в пределе.